# Set checkbox to checked based on other inputs values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, user-experience

I want to set the checkbox input to checked if specific inputs is filled with values but with the option to change checkbox to unchecked again.

the business need requires that this checkbox should be set to checked automatically if the user filled the required inputs but with the option to set it back to unchecked if he wants.(user experience stuff)[usecase demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpF4L.png)

Consider the following code:

```
     autoAddFinalEvaluation = () => {
      const {channelValue, evaluationValue, txtValue} = this.state;
      if(channelValue !== null && evaluationValue !== null && txtValue !== '') {
        this.setState({
          checked: true
        })
      } 
    }
```

i updated the state dynamically like this

```
  autoAddFinalEvaluation = () => {
    const {channelValue, evaluationValue, txtValue} = this.state;
    if(channelValue !== null && evaluationValue !== null && txtValue !== '') {
      this.setState({
        checked: !this.state.checked
      })
    }
  }
```

now i can set the checkbox normally but still not working as i expect, while filling the 3rd input(text area) the checkbox switches from true to false and vice versa.

Comment: Could you be more specific ? Consider adding more code or explain better your needs.

Comment: please edit your formatting

Comment: @Hurobaki is it ok now ?

Comment: @Abd-AllahEid Is there a way that you provide me you React code ? So I can test it on my own

Comment: @Hurobaki Thanks for your time & effort, it works now as the answer below suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is "autoAddFinalEvaluation" is executed after you uncheck the checkbox while it should be called only when input changed in what we may call parent field (The field which input causes the checkbox to be checked).

Comment: Your last statement ensures that the problem is calling the function more than required.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort, as you said the problem in my code was that the onChange function was bound to the parent component that contain the inputs, now when i handled each input independently it works fine.